# OleDbException when calling OleDbConnection open method

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to manipulate an excel 2010 file in my asp net mvc application.

This is the code:

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\teste.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";";
OleDbConnection conexao = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
conexao.Open();
```

Open() method trows an exception I cannot find out why.

**Exception:**

```
    Erro: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Failure creating file.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at Gedi.Controllers.AdminController.File() in c:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Gedi\Gedi\Controllers\AdminController.cs:line 62
```

Comment: Is the file opened at the same time you are accessing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable fro the file-path with a verbatim string:

```
string path = @"c:\teste.xlsx";
string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";");", path);
```

Otherwise you need to mask the backslashes like `"c:\\teste.xlsx"`: